Using ceramic capacitors instead of electrolytic capacitors
I'm using a circuit to charge and discharge a capactior at different rates, where the capacitor has a capacitance of 10uF. I have tested the circuit in a breadboard and it worked well with an electrolytic capacitor, however, when assembling the circuit in a PCB, I have stumbled upon SMT 0805 ceramic capacitors with 10uF.
Using one of these would result in a pretty good reduction in space, but would it work with the same results as the electrolytic cap?
My main goal is to make sure the capacitor still charges and discharges as I tested on the breadboard. As the RC constant stays the same with either a electrolytic or a ceramic cap, I believe it would work, but then why would someone use a bigger, more expensive electrolytic cap over a ceramic one?
This is the circuit I'm using, where the testpoint is the input of a analog comparator IC. It's a low current and low voltage circuit(3.3V and 5V).


they degrade with voltage, so to know for sure it would be nice to understand what are you trying to achieve.

@TQQQ I'm using a voltage comparator as an on/off circuit. When I press the on button, the circuit charges the capacitor through the transistor, so the comparator input stays at over 1.27 volts while the other input (which comes from a microcontroller) starts up.

then you are going to be ok

The ceramic cap may change value from 10 uF at 0 V to 2 uF at rated voltage. The electrolytic is relatively voltage-insensitive. If you can tolerate the variable capacity, then go for it.

Is there a reason you can't increase the resistance and use a smaller capacitor?

As Neil_UK alluded to, ceramic caps have a capacitance which changes significantly with DC bias. Without knowing more about your application I would not assume identical performance.

What's the maximum voltage across the cap and how much tolerance in the RC time constant can you live with? (Would +/-30% be okay, for example?)

@Drew Specifically, type-II and type-III ceramic caps have a voltage dependence. A 10 μF capacitor is definitely not type-I, but it should be noted.

Ceramic capacitors of that value and size (or, especially, smaller) change value with voltage, are temperature-sensitive and age quite a bit compared to electrolytic capacitors.
Here is a simulation of a couple specific Murata 10uF/16V parts charging towards +5V through a 75kΩ resistor, compared to an ideal 10uF capacitor (green trace).

In some cases parts drop in value by 80% at less than 5V bias, so you can get a lot of variation, especially as the capacitor voltage passes a volt or two.

Do ceramics age worse than electrolytic? I would would have guessed the opposite.

@Tyassin Yes and no. Ceramic capacitors change in value fairly quickly at first and then slowly, but the ESR stays low. Electrolytic capacitors maintain value but the ESR increases gradually over the lifetime, which does not affect timing circuits such as this one. Lifetime tends to be adequate (many decades) in a  circuit like this  provided the environment isn't too hot.
